# Proton 'Laser' ? could we get a laser-like effect?

Tags: laser, fusion

This is a speculative question.

question:
Can we gain protons, by smashing a high speed proton into a hydrogen plasma?

Background:
I was thinking about how lasers repeatedly send the photons thru the gas to get it to discharge more photons on the same wavelength.

And wondered if you could do the same thing with neutrons.  But, I couldn't think of a way to reflect neutrons.  But protons, are magnetic.  so then the idea was to try protons.

I'm guessing that, at high speeds, a simple magnetic field would not be enough to reverse the direction of a proton -- it would "punch thru".  But, if the goal is just to get it to go thru the target multiple times -- then the answer is already solved (I think) -- super-colliders gradually deflect the high-speed protons into a circular trajectory.

The part I'm not sure about, is how to get more protons to be emitted -- even if 2 protons smashed together, you might get fusion, but I'm not sure if you'd actually get a laser-like effect where it emits a new proton.

Thus, the question...     Thanks in advance!
-Chuck

Comment: "lasers repeatedly send the photons thru the gas to get it to discharge more photons on the same wavelength. " This is not a description of lasers. The discharge of photons has to be coherent, i.e. the phases are also fixed. please read the physics paragraph on laser action http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser#Laser_physics. You cannot get that with proton proton interactions which are incoherent, in addition to the problem of charge conservation that Kyle mentions

Comment: Thank you, I think I have my answer, and it's:  No - it won't work.

Comment: ps.  for the laser, I was trying to describe it's "mechanical" workings, such as: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_construction

Answer (score 1):

[Conservation of charge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_conservation) would not allow the reaction
$$
p+p\to p+p+p
$$
because you have +2q charge on the left and +3q charge on the right.